# Xamarin.iOS share extension for video files

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've implemented a share extension for my project and there seems to be an issue with video files. when I use the  itemProvider.LoadItem  function to get the object.

The extension works fine with files that conform to:

UTType.Audio and
UTType.Image

When I share videos, I always check if the file conforms to:

attachment.HasItemConformingTo (UTType.Movie)

I've also logged the videos exact type signings using insights:

com.apple.quicktime-movie (gallery) and
public.video (iMovie)

I've then modified the exact type I use in the itemProvider.LoadItem to match the one recorded by insights

Then end result is that the NSObject always comes back as null with the NSError always set to the following:
No item available for requested type identifier.

Has anyone else run into the issue?
Am I doing something wrong?